# I can't figure out how to activate this function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I am making an app with a function as shown here:

```
func RMC(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        annotation.title = "My Car"
```

And I want to activate it in a @IBA function with this code:

```
RMC(CLLocationManager, locations: [CLLocation])
```

It comes up with this error:
Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationManager.Type' to expected argument type 'CLLocationManager'

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate a CLLocationManager object and pass it in. At your call site right now, you're just referring to the type `CLLocationManager` instead of passing in an instance of `CLLocationManager`. You're doing the same in the array of `CLLocations`, but you generally don't instantiate those yourself. You'll have to change the call to:

```
RMC(CLLocationManager(), locations: [])
```

Also, the first line line in your function where you create a new `CLLocationManager` is redundant and should be removed, as it makes it impossible to use the `CLLocationManater` object that was passed in (it may be a compiler error, but I haven't tested to make sure)